Trying to link two different rust crates, using different toolchains throu a C ABI
I have two rust crates, one is a Vulkan bindings wrapper, another is a rustgpu wrapper for compiling to spirv.
Rustgpu is currently bound to specific rust versions and I do not want to add that restriction to my codebase, but I want to call the rus gpu compiler directly, i.e. not through system calls.
To that effect, I am trying to compile my rustgpu wrapper as either a static or dynamic library.
If I compile it as a static library then at linking time I get duplicate symbol errors because both binaries will include the std symbols.
If I try using libloading, to load the dynamic .so at runtime I get this error:
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Zcodegen-backend=crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librustc_codegen_spirv.so -Zbinary-dep-depinfo -Csymbol-mangling-version=v0 '-Zcrate-attr=feature(register_tool)' '-Zcrate-attr=register_tool(rust_gpu)' -Coverflow-checks=off -Cdebug-assertions=off -Zinline-mir=off '-Cllvm-args=--module-output=multiple --spirv-metadata=full --scalar-block-layout --preserve-bindings' --target spirv-unknown-vulkan1.2 --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=split-debuginfo --print=crate-name --print=cfg` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  error: couldn't load codegen backend /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/vulkan_bindings/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/test_shaders/spinning_triangle/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librustc_codegen_spirv.so/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/vulkan_bindings/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/test_shaders/spinning_triangle/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librustc_codegen_spirv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I need to either, find a way to eliminate the duplicate symbols described in the link for the static library, or figure out what is happening when loading the dynamic symbol.
All I am doing for loading dynamically is:
fn rust_to_spirv(
    val: &safer_ffi::string::String,
) -> safer_ffi::slice::slice_boxed<safer_ffi::slice::slice_boxed<u8>>
{
    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new(
            "crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librust_gpu_parsing.so",
        )
        .unwrap();
        let func: libloading::Symbol<
            unsafe extern "C" fn(
                &safer_ffi::string::String,
            ) -> safer_ffi::slice::slice_boxed<
                safer_ffi::slice::slice_boxed<u8>,
            >,
        > = lib.get(b"rust_to_spirv").unwrap();
        func(val)
    }
}

I have checked and there is a librustc_codegen_spirv.so on the target/release/ directory, right besides the so file I am loading. I am not sure why my binary is searching this path:
/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/vulkan_bindings/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/test_shaders/spinning_triangle/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librustc_codegen_spirv.so/home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/vulkan_bindings/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/test_shaders/spinning_triangle/crates/rust_gpu_parsing/target/release/librustc_codegen_spirv.so
What could be causing that concatenation?
I used readelf to try to print the rpath of librust_gpu_parsing.so and there is no rpath or runpath set.

The error you've quoted is not caused by the code you've quoted, but rather by the (incorrect) manner in which you have attempted compilation.  Please detail how you are invoking the compilation, including command line options etc.  If using a build tool like cargo, include its configuration (eg relevant parts of Cargo.toml and any config.tomls).
